# Generalised Differentiation of Product of Quotients

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives

Suppose we have functions $f_i(x),g_i(x)$, how could we express
$$\frac{d}{dx}\prod_{i=1}^n\frac{f_i(x)}{g_i(x)}$$
in a nice form? I am aware of the [generalised product rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/549411/generalizing-the-product-rule) however I was interested in how we may use this to determine an expression for this derivative. I feel as though we could consider
$$\frac{d}{dx}\prod_{i=1}^n{f_i(x)}({g_i(x)})^{-1}=\frac{d}{dx}\prod_{i=1}^nh_i(x)$$
and apply the generalised product rule to this? An answer to this would be much appreciated!

Comment: Derivatives of products, quotients, ... can be nicely computed using the “logarithmic derivative” $\frac{F'(x)}{F(x)} = \frac{d}{dx} \ln F(x)$.

Comment: So @MartinR if $F(x)=\prod_{i=1}^n h_i(x)$, then $F^\prime(x) = F(x) \frac{d}{dx}\ln(F(x)) = F(x) \frac{d}{dx}\left[ \ln\left( \frac{f_1(x)}{g_1(x)} \right)+\cdots+\ln\left(\frac{f_n(x)}{g_n(x)}\right) \right]$?

Comment: The point is that the logarithmic derivative of a product (quotient) is the sum (difference) of the logarithmic derivatives. So on the RHS you get $F(x) \sum(f_k'(x)/f_k(x) - g_k'(x)/g_k(x))$. But of course you would get the same result by just applying the product rule to $\prod h_i$ and the quotient rule to each $h_i =  f_i/g_i$.